Читаемость SQL запроса при использовании классов и конcтант в PHP
Решил избавиться от прямой зависимости названий таблиц и полей. Для этого использовал классы и константы. Есть ли какой-то способ хоть чучуть улучшить читаемость? Или лучше уже быть не может?
$queryInfo = "
    SELECT
        " . Tables::POSTS . "." . PostsColumns::POST_PROMPT . ",
        " . Tables::POSTS . "." . PostsColumns::POST_ID . ",
        " . Tables::POSTS . "." . PostsColumns::POST_FOLDER . ",
        " . Tables::POSTS . "." . PostsColumns::POST_IMAGES_TYPE . ",
        " . Tables::POSTS . "." . PostsColumns::POST_LANGUAGE . ",
        " . Tables::TOPICS . "." . TopicsColumns::TOPIC_ID . ",
        " . Tables::TOPICS . "." . TopicsColumns::TOPIC_NAME . ",
        " . Tables::TOPICS . "." . TopicsColumns::TOPIC_FOLDER . ",
        " . Tables::TOPICS . "." . TopicsColumns::TOPIC_COVER . "
    FROM 
        " . Tables::IMAGES . "
    JOIN 
        " . Tables::POSTS . " ON " . Tables::IMAGES . "." . ImagesColumns::IMAGE_POST_ID . " = " . Tables::POSTS . "." . PostsColumns::POST_ID . "
    JOIN
        " . Tables::LINKS . " ON " . Tables::IMAGES . "." . ImagesColumns::IMAGE_POST_ID . " = " . Tables::LINKS . "." . LinksColumns::LINK_POST_ID . "
    JOIN
        " . Tables::TOPICS . " ON " . Tables::LINKS . "." . LinksColumns::LINK_TOPIC_ID . " = " . Tables::TOPICS . "." . TopicsColumns::TOPIC_ID . "
    WHERE 
        " . Tables::IMAGES . "." . ImagesColumns::IMAGE_NAME . " = ?
        AND " . Tables::LINKS . "." . LinksColumns::LINK_MAIN_TOPIC . " = 1
";


Чем текущая читаемость вас не устраивает?

Есть ли какой-то способ хоть чучуть улучшить читаемость? Да. Перейти наконец на PDO. И использовать вменяемые имена-плейсхолдеры.

Все как-то запутано получилось. Для восприятия. Однако, после переноса соединений на отдельные строки от имен таблиц, стало легче.

Асинхронность вошла в чат

Возможно стоит попробовать функцию sprintf

@abu чтобы испортить читабельность окончательно? :)

@Akina он же идентфикаторы туда суёт, а не данные. Плейсхолдеры тут не при делах совсем.

@Ипатьев Дык эта... он конкатенирует в запрос, скажем, Tables::POSTS или ImagesColumns::IMAGE_NAME, и туда конкатенируется строковое значение, которое имя таблицы/файла, так? Ну дык теперь представь - мы на этом месте пишем плейсхолдер, к примеру, @tPosts или @cImageName, а потом в BindParameter по этому имени вяжем значение из Tables::POSTS / ImagesColumns::IMAGE_NAME. Если такая технология не умеет имена объектов - их соответственно втыкаем через REPLACE(). Финально те же яйцы, но только без конкатенации в тексте запроса. Чисто паттерн, который потом кодом превращается в SQL.

Но зато сам текст запроса чист и хорошо читаем. PS. Понимаю, что это чуть не свой фреймворк, но если товарищ хочет...

@Akina я ничего не понял. при чем тут REPLACE? И никакое там не строковое значение, а идентификатор. posts BindParameter привяжет СТРОКУ 'posts'. В кавычках. И никакое  REPLACE() не поможет.

Есть такая поговорка, "Дурная голова ногам покоя не даёт". И ещё одна, "Когда коту делать нечего, он гигиеной занимается".
Вот ваши идеи ровно из этого сектора.

Решил избавиться от прямой зависимости названий таблиц и полей.

Для начала надо задать себе вопрос - ЗАЧЕМ. Что вдруг такого это зависимости, и почему надо вдруг бежать усложнять весь код в 10 раз на пустом месте. Ведь это ещё примитивный запрос. А более-менее сложный вообще прочесть будет невозможно. И всё это - совершенно без причины. Что-то жёлтое в голову ударило.

У меня есть планы изменить имена некоторых таблиц и полей. Делать постепенно будет проблематично. Да, основные запросы это вообще безумие получается. Но вместо имен таблиц решил использовать алиасы, и вроде не все так плачебно.

Ну вот надо взять и изменить. Переписать несколько запросов. А не ВСЕ запросы на это уродство.
